Issues Editing Kotlin Code in Flutter Project with Android Studio: Preferences Not Saving
StackOverflow community!
I'm working on a Flutter project that includes both Dart and native Kotlin code. Initially, I used VS Code for the Flutter part and recently incorporated Kotlin for Android-specific functionality. To streamline my development process, I've attempted to switch to Android Studio, expecting to leverage its robust support for both Kotlin and Flutter.
However, I've run into an issue that has significantly hindered my workflow. When I open the entire Flutter project in Android Studio, the IDE's Kotlin code analysis and suggestion features do not perform as well as they do when I only open the android/ directory of the Flutter project. This discrepancy makes it challenging to work on the Kotlin part with the same efficiency as when the android/ directory is opened independently, which in turn, impedes my ability to edit the Flutter/Dart part effectively within the same IDE.
Here's a summary of my dilemma:
Opening the entire Flutter project in Android Studio disrupts Kotlin code analysis.
Opening only the android/ directory allows for proper Kotlin support but restricts Flutter editing capabilities.
Has anyone encountered this issue or a similar one? Any advice on configuring Android Studio to accommodate both Kotlin and Flutter development seamlessly would be greatly appreciated. Specifically, if there are known fixes or workarounds to ensure preference settings are saved and applied consistently, I would like to learn.
Thank you very much for any help or insight you can provide!
I've tried to enable the option within Android Studio to analyze Kotlin code in Flutter preferences, hoping to resolve this issue. Unfortunately, my settings do not seem to persist after closing and reopening Preferences Dialog
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.4, on Linux Mint 21.2 6.5.0-25-generic, locale
    en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.87.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!



Yes. You need to open 2 projects. One for flutter and one for android folder inside flutter project.

I don't now how mark that the issue was solved, so moderators, can you help me out
